# Why does stopping Standalone Spark master fail with "no org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master to stop"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

Stopping standalone spark master fails with the following message:

```
$ ./sbin/stop-master.sh 
no org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master to stop
```

Why? There is one Spark Standalone master up and running.

Answer (score 4):

Spark master was started under different user.

/tmp/Spark-ec2-user-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1.pid

Was not accessible.Had to login under different user who actually started the stand alone cluster manager master.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to open the master WebUI page on browser where it clearly mentioned that Spark Master is running on port `7077`.

However, while trying to stop using `stop-all.sh`, was facing `no org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master to stop` . So I tried a different method - to find what process is running on port `7077` using below command :

`lsof -i :7077`

I got the result as `java` with a PID of `112099`

Used the below command to kill that process :

`kill 112099`

After this when I checked the WebUI, it had stopped working. Successfully killed the Spark Master.